# Combining two multidimensional arrays and sum only one key w/ numerical value - PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have to combine two multidimensional arrays (4 levels deep) while summing up the numerical values under each item. The structure of the two arrays are identical other than the values mentioned.

Array1:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => AB00
            [item_text] => Alcoholic beverages
            [value] => 233
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => AP00
            [item_text] => Apparel and services
            [value] => 1080
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APC0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Children under 2
                            [value] => 79
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APO0
                            [item_text] => Other apparel products and services
                            [value] => 131
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APM0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Men and boys
                            [value] => 204
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APM2
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Boys, 2 to 15
                                            [value] => 41
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APM1
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Men, 16 and over
                                            [value] => 163
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APF0
                            [item_text] => Footwear
                            [value] => 241
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APW0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Women and girls
                            [value] => 425
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APW2
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Girls, 2 to 15
                                            [value] => 78
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APW1
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Women, 16 and over
                                            [value] => 347
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

And Array2:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => AB00
            [item_text] => Alcoholic beverages
            [value] => 296
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_code] => AP00
            [item_text] => Apparel and services
            [value] => 1225
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APC0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Children under 2
                            [value] => 73
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APO0
                            [item_text] => Other apparel products and services
                            [value] => 163
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APF0
                            [item_text] => Footwear
                            [value] => 265
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APM0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Men and boys
                            [value] => 278
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APM2
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Boys, 2 to 15
                                            [value] => 61
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APM1
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Men, 16 and over
                                            [value] => 217
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [item_code] => APW0
                            [item_text] => Apparel, Women and girls
                            [value] => 447
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APW2
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Girls, 2 to 15
                                            [value] => 95
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_code] => APW1
                                            [item_text] => Apparel, Women, 16 and over
                                            [value] => 353
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

My goal is to combine these two arrays and sum the [value] numerical keys. My progress so far:

```
foreach ($Array2 as $key => $values) {
foreach ($values as $name => $value) {
    if(!is_array($Array1[$key])) {
        $Array1[$key] = array(); 
    }
    $finalArr[$key][$name] += $value;
}
```

}

Sorry to be long-winded with my question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Will they always be in this structure (i.e. 4 levels deep)?

Comment: Yes, the structure will remain the same.

Comment: So you want only to add each pair of matching values from array1 to array2?  So the merged array has everything else the same but a sum of the two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will recursively merge two arrays and apply a callback to determine what to do with matching-key non-array values.

```
function array_merge_map_recursive($r1, $r2, $callback) {
    $merged = array();
    foreach ($r1 as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($r2[$k])) {
            $merged[$k] = $v;
        }
        elseif (!is_array($v)) {
            $merged[$k] = $callback($k,$v,$r2[$k]);
        }
        else {
            $merged[$k] = array_merge_map_recursive($v,$r2[$k],$callback);
        }
    }
    return $merged;
}
```

The callback will sum the two elements if the key is 'value', otherwise if they're the same it will leave it alone, and if they're not the same it will wrap them in an array.  If you want to sum any numerical values, regardless of key, you can change the first `if` to something like `if (is_numeric($v1))`.

This syntax requires PHP 5.3, but it can be rewritten for earlier versions pretty easily.

```
$sumIfValue = function($key,$v1,$v2) {
    if ($key==='value') {
        return $v1 + $v2;
    } elseif ($v1===$v2) {
        return $v1;
    } else {
        return array($v1,$v2);
    }
};
```

Then you can call it like this (where your two arrays are `$array1` and `$array2`):

```
$merged = array_merge_map_recursive($array1, $array2, $sumIfValue);
```

Comment: I corrected it from the original one I wrote to do what I think you're looking for.  Try running it and var_dump'ing the output to make sure you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To save on resources [Use merge array first](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)